# How do I pick elements from two arrays such that the sum is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have two arrays of equal length, and I can choose from either array1 or array2, and the output of the sum must be the smallest. However, the number of times I picked the element from array1 must be the same as I picked from array2.

Example:

`array1 = [2, 3, 5, 1]`

`array2 = [1, 2, 3, 2]`

The output will be 8, because:

```
At index0: I picked 2 from array1.
At index1: I picked 2 from array2.
At index2: I picked 3 from array2.
At index3: I picked 1 from array1.
```

My current approach: I sort the pair of array based on the element on array1. So I picked array1 at index0 and index1, then array2 at index2 and index3.

Example after sorted:

`array1 = [1, 2, 3, 5]`

`array2 = [2, 1, 2, 3]`

```
At index0: I picked 1 from array1.
At index1: I picked 2 from array1.
At index2: I picked 2 from array2.
At index3: I picked 3 from array2.
```

However, I may face a problem when the array is like this:

`array1 = [2, 3, 5, 1]`

`array2 = [1, 7, 6, 2]`

After sorted based on array1:

`array1 = [1, 2, 3, 5]`

`array2 = [2, 1, 7, 6]`

```
At index0: I picked 1 from array1.
At index1: I picked 2 from array1.
At index2: I picked 7 from array2.
At index3: I picked 6 from array2.
```

When the ideal solution is:

```
At index0: I picked 2 from array2.
At index1: I picked 1 from array2.
At index2: I picked 3 from array1.
At index3: I picked 5 from array1.
```

Can someone help me out with this? Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear how elements are picked from arrays.

Comment: Let's say there are 2 arrays, a[i] and b[i].

I have to output the smallest sum number based on the input of the 2 arrays. However, the number of times of elements picked from a[i] must be the same as b[i].

Example:
Left side is input of a[i], right side is input of b[i]

2 1, 
3 2, 
5 3, 
1 2. 

The output will be 8. Because I picked a[i] at index 0, b[i] at index 1 and 2, and a[i] at index 3, and it gives the smallest sum value.

Comment: The minimum sum for the first example of arrays is array1[3] + array2[0]

Comment: No, let's say if there are 4 inputs for array1 and array2, I have to pick 2 inputs from array1 and array2. So it would be a[0] + b[1] + b[2] + a[3] = 8, which will give the smallest sum value.

Comment: Is there a constraint on how many you have to pick? If not, then it's clear that picking just 1 from each array is optimal like @Scheff said.

Comment: As I understand: for each index, you have to pick either from array1 or array2, but final pick count of array1 should be identical to the count from array2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute difference array1 - array2:

```
array1 = [2, 3, 5, 1]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 2]

diff   = [1, 1 ,2, -1]
index  = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Sort it (and remember indexes):

```
sorted_diff: [-1, 1, 1, 2]
index2     : [ 3, 0, 1, 2]
            array1 | array2
```

You have to negate half the array to obtain minimum sum., so index1, index2 are from array2.

Example2:

```
array1 = [2, 3, 5, 1]
array2 = [1, 7, 6, 2]

diff   = [1, -4 ,-1, -1]
index  = [0, 1, 2, 3]

sorted = [-4, -1, -1, 1]
index2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 0]
        array1 | array2
```

So take from array2 index3, index0.

Comment: So, negative diff -> element of array1 is smaller than element of array2. (Positive diff - the opposite.) Sorting the diff array moves indices to choose from array1 to front and indices to choose from array2 to back. I needed a while until I understood how/why your solution works... ;-)

Comment: Hey, this is really helpful! Thank you so much!